# Filling Array with 2d function values in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I am wondering if there is a 1 liner to do this assignment in the array in Julia:

```
h = .1
L = 1

x = 0:h:L
n = length(x)

discretized = zeros(n,n)

#really any old function
f(x,y) = x*y + cos(x) + sin(y)

for i in 1:n
   for j in 1:n
       discretized[i, j] = f(x[i], x[j])
   end
end
```

Or do I explicitly have to write out the loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
discretized = [f(i, j) for i in x, j in x]
```

For more information, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Comprehensions-1

Edit: Based on the comments, here's a brief overview of what the `:` operator does in indexing:

```
julia> a = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> a[:]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> ans === a
false

julia> a[:] .= [2, 3, 4]
3-element view(::Array{Int64,1}, :) with eltype Int64:
 2
 3
 4

julia> a
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
```

Comment: Ok, i'm unclear on what the `:` operator does exactly. It makes sense in your example, and coming from python the list comprehension makes sense. But out of curiosity, I have seen people do things along the lines of `discretized[:] = ` something. Could this be used here?

Comment: Not really, since you want to construct an array, not modify its values.  The `:` operator can be used to create a range, but in array indexing it can translate to "each index of" the array.  I edited my post with some details.

Comment: To be even more clear; syntax such as `a[:] .= x` is a combination of indexing and broadcasting.  Indexing (explained here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-array-indexing-1) can be of the form `a[start:end]` to select a range along a dimension, or you can simply use a lone colon to mean "everything along this dimension". (Note that Python allows you to do do things like `a[start:]` to implicitly go from a starting point to the end, in Julia you must explicitly write `end`)

Comment: Broadcasting is the "dot" operator that you will see all over the place (such as `foo.(x)` or `a .*= 3`).  It means "do a scalar operation to each element of this collection" (read more about it here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1).  In this case, if you wanted to set every element in an array to `0`, you could do `a[:] .= 0`, or equivalently, `a .= 0`.  If you wanted to set only a range to zero, you could do `a[2:5] .= 0`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could broadcast the function over an array an its transpose - julia will return the result as a 2d Array:

```
x = 0:0.1:1
f(x,y) = x*y + cos(x) + sin(y)

A = f.(x,x')  # the `.` before the bracket broadcasts the dimensions
# 11×11 Array{Float64,2}
```

or if have more complicated expressions or functions and don't want to write out lots of dots use the `@.` macro, e.g:

```
A = @. f(x,x') + x^2
```

Once `A` already exists, you can also do

```
@. A = f(x,x') + x^2
```

which uses `.=` to write the result locally to each element of `A`, and hence is non-allocating.

Broadcasting goes much further than this easy extension of scalar functions to arrays, allowing "fusion" of multiple calculations into a single fast operation https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots